# Parse.con Error/success was not called when updating object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I was in trouble because one of my function in Javascript which updates a Parse Object doesn't work but I don't know why !! I have almost the same function which works !

This is my function :

```
function setRecommendationToDone(user){
var v = document.getElementById("prevent_box");

for(var i=0;i<v.childNodes.length-1;i++){

    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox" + i);
    if(checkbox.checked){
        var id_product = checkbox.parentElement.getAttribute("id");

        var query = new Parse.Query("actions");
        query.equalTo("user", user);
        query.equalTo("id_produit", id_product);
          query.first({
            success: function(results) {
                results.set("Etat","Fait");
                results.save();
            }, error: function(error){

            }
      });

    }
}
```

}

Firstly, I thinked It was caused by the fact the save was in a loop but i test it without but still the same error : "success/error was not called". I'm used with this error with Cloud Code but this is not Cloud Code here !!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `id_produit` a typo?

Comment: Is one of my column of the class which I do the query

Comment: Right, just wondering if it's meant to be `id_product`.

Comment: Haha I would liked that's so easy ;)

Comment: How do you know success or error are never called? Did you put breakpoints inside them? Alerts?

Comment: I replace the .save() by save(null, {
  success: function(result) {
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert('Failed to update object, with error code: ' + error.message);
  }
});

Comment: So the success/error callbacks from `first()` are being invoked, just not the ones from `save()`?

Comment: Do you have a "beforeSave" in CloudCode for your class? I beleive this code runs on a frontend but on the backend side you need to call response.success()/response.error() if you use beforeSave there.

Comment: Yeah  that's the problem thank you !  I completly forgot my beforeSave function !